# Fedora Linux ath10k firmware problem. Fresh install

Tags: fedora, kernel, firmware

I Just installed fedora and on reboot there was this error on the Problem Reporting app, that (as it turns out it cant't be reported????) saying something about ath10k firmware.

Edit: It happens again when I reboot!

[image: error]

[image: details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1155863/754057

You could try to update your Firmware like this:

- `fwupdmgr get-updates`
- `fwupdmgr get-devices`

Or you install the *.cab drivers with fwupdmgr as written in the Ubuntu Forum, this tool will work the same way in Fedora.

This GitHub Page is probably very helpful for you: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware

If you update your System (`sudo dnf upgrade`) it could be resolved in the Feature as well.

When this is not the proper solution we need to dig deeper there.

Greets